# htaccess and REQUEST_URI to match from list and redirect

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a iso 639-1 language list like this:

```
en, fr, de, es, ja
```

If request URL has one of the code from my list, user will be redirected.
If language code doesn't exists in array (for example aa,bb), user will be redirected to default index page.
Language code is always 2 characters and followed by domain name.

Redirect examples like this:

```
http://example.com/en/index.html  --> http://example.com/index_en.html
http://example.com/fr/index.html  --> http://example.com/index_fr.html
http://example.com/de/index.html  --> http://example.com/index_de.html
http://example.com/es/index.html  --> http://example.com/index_es.html
http://example.com/ja/index.html  --> http://example.com/index_ja.html

http://example.com/aa/index.html  --> http://example.com/index.html
http://example.com/bb/index.html  --> http://example.com/index.html
http://example.com/zz/index.html  --> http://example.com/index.html
```

I tried like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^example.com/(en|fr|de|es|ja)/ [NC]
RewriteRule . /index_$1.html [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(en|fr|de|es|ja)/index\.html$ /index_$1.html [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^[a-z]{2}/index\.html$ /index.html [L,NC]
```